# How to sum of two column into third column for all rows

Tags: php, mysql

How to sum of two column into third column or in output  for all rows

```
order_id  english maths grand_total 
   1         10      10         20
   2         20      5          25
   3         10      10         20
```

I run this query     "select sum(english+maths)as grand_total from table"
 and the result is

```
grand_total
   20
```

I get only first row not all rows how to get sum of all row in one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select order_id, english, maths, english + maths as grand_total from table
```

There isn't any need of an aggregate function as you don't want your data grouped in any way.

Comment: There might be some other issue. Arithmetic operations such as addition don't have anything to do with character collation :)

Comment: this warning shows in my sql query #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'english+maths as total from table